# getJSON script returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I have had a look around on here and a number of other sites for the correct way to create an HTML table from and external json link and have come up with the below.

I am trying to pull the username and number of votes and display them in the table, multiple rows are created, all populated with "undefined".

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link re="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="ragnarok_table">
   <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Votes</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=[REMOVED]&month=current&format=json", function(data){
  var ragnarok_data = '';
  $.each(data, function(val){
   ragnarok_data += '<tr>';
   ragnarok_data += '<td>'+val.nickname+'</td>';
   ragnarok_data += '<td>'+val.votes+'</td>';
   ragnarok_data += '</tr>';
  });
  $('#ragnarok_table').append(ragnarok_data);
 });
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I can see that others have run into this issue too, however, this is my first time diving into Javascript; the other questions have completely different code and the answers dont seem to work here. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There are no errors, thats whats confusing me

Comment: You are not looping over the array!!! You are looping over the object. Simple debugging would show you that.

Comment: try `$.each(data, function(index, val)` - note, jQuery $.each retards, ... sorry, reverses index/value compared to Array#forEach

Comment: a) Yes b) No c) 
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=current&format=json"

Comment: there have been two comments and an answer that fixes your error :p

Comment: As ive said in the original post, this is the first time ive tried using javascript :/

Comment: This is where jQuery sux ... $.each works with anything, so you can't even tell that you're doing it wrong :p

Comment: Sorry for what must have been a stupid question, still trying to get to grips with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `.forEach` on `data.voters`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link re="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="ragnarok_table">
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=current&format=json", function(data) {
        var ragnarok_data = '';
        data.voters.forEach(function (val) {
          ragnarok_data += '<tr>';
          ragnarok_data += '<td>' + val.nickname + '</td>';
          ragnarok_data += '<td>' + val.votes + '</td>';
          ragnarok_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ragnarok_table').append(ragnarok_data);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, if you are dead set on `jQuery`, modify your `$.each` to be on the array you want data from `data.voters`, and to properly get the value:

```
$.each(data.voters, function (ignore, val) {
```

The second argument is the value, the first argument is the index. See more here:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Thank you very much for this - where would you recommended is the best place to learn JS?

Comment: @maxbrad124, read books on the subject, read MDN articles, take as many online courses as you can, and build/contribute to open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .each as below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link re="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="ragnarok_table">
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("https://ark-servers.net/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=R72Uo7jcAXCVBjx1eGtDm8itWlrU59GHnuy&month=current&format=json", function(data) {
        var ragnarok_data = '';
        /*data.voters.forEach(function (val) {
        */
        $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.voters))).each(function() {  
          ragnarok_data += '<tr>';
          ragnarok_data += '<td>' + this.nickname + '</td>';
          ragnarok_data += '<td>' + this.votes + '</td>';
          ragnarok_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ragnarok_table').append(ragnarok_data);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to _stringify_ and _parse_ `data.voters` as JSON. See my answer.